# How to push a string into array

Tags: ruby, arrays, regex

I am matching a pattern and i need to split and push it into an array.

```
a = Array.new
doc = "<span>Hi welcome to world</span>"
len = doc.length
puts doc.scan(/o/)
a << doc.scan(/o/)
puts a.length
```

Output for the above code is

```
o
o
o
1
```

The length of array is **1**

I want the length of array to be **3**

Instead of pushing a complete string into an array. i want to push it as three different elements

Comment: try a << firstString << secondString ... ?

Comment: Why do you expect the length of the array to be 4?

Comment: Fyi. You pushed an array into array. So `a` has a  second element which is the array produced from `doc.scan(/o/)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`Array#concat`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-concat) method.

```
a = Array.new
doc = "<span>Hi welcome to world</span>"
len = doc.length
puts doc.scan(/o/)
a.concat doc.scan(/o/)
puts a.length # => 3
```

`doc.scan(/o/)` gives you `['o', 'o', 'o']`. And `a << doc.scan(/o/)` gives you `[['o', 'o', 'o']]`, not `['o', 'o', 'o']`. That's why you are getting the size of `a` as `1`.

What you want to achieve can be made using `Array#concat`. Because `a.concat doc.scan(/o/)` will give you exactly `['o', 'o', 'o']`, and thus size of `a` is now `3`.

But you could write it as:

```
doc = "<span>Hi welcome to world</span>"
len = doc.length
puts doc.scan(/o/)
a = doc.scan(/o/)
puts a.length # => 3
```

Looking at your this mini code `a = Array.new` is not needed.

Comment: also maybe simply `a += doc.scan(/o/)` ?

Comment: @shivam It will create a new object.. :)

Comment: You could also pass a block to `scan`: `doc.scan(/o/) { |m| a << m }`